# How to change the color of the vim ruler?

Tags: vimrc, colorscheme, ruler

was hoping someone could help me in changing the color of the ruler in vim? Specifically, the opacity as I'm trying to make it match the rest of my vim opacity, but can't seem to pinpoint where exactly in the colorscheme files it can be found.

Any help you could offer would be greatly appreciated as I couldn't find a whole lot on this just from my google searching. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The highlight group for the default ruler is `Normal`.  If you just want to adjust the opacity for everything, this might work.

In vim there is not a built-in way to adjust the standard ruler's colors independently from the regular buffer text.  In neovim, there is `MsgArea`, although that covers more than just the ruler.

One workaround is to use your own ruler format

```
:set rulerformat=%#Ruler#%l,%c%V%=%P
```

This will effectively render the default ruler using the `Ruler` group.